# BodyParser Behavior

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl, express

I am sending a POST request with cURL :

```
curl http://tarvos.local:8080/partial_Users/2 -d '{currentPage : 1, firstID : 53d62fc6642aecf45c8b456f }'
```

In my NodeJS application, the request goes through the bodyParser.json() middleware. I have another middleware that processes the request :

```
app.post('/partial_Users/:page', function(req, res, next) {

    var destinationPage = req.params.page;
    var currentPage = req.body.currentPage;
    var firstID = req.body.firstID;
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(''+ currentPage + firstID)
    [...]
}
```

In this situation, I would expect `req.body.currentPage` to return 1. In fact, it returns 'undefined'.

I have noticed that when I do a console.log(req.body), I get the following string :

`{ '{currentPage : 1, firstID : 53d62fc6642aecf45c8b456f }': '' }`

It becomes apparent now that `req.body.currentPage` would return undefined. For some reason, bodyParser is not parsing JSON properly. The same behaviour is seen for the`req.body.firstID`.

Either I am not using BodyParser properly, or my JSON request in not structured properly maybe?

Comment: My guess is bodyparser is expecting `Content-type: application/json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to your curl command line, otherwise `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is assumed.